# Python Error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '00nan'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from yellowbrick.features.importances import FeatureImportances


# First, let’s load the data:
# read the data
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\path_here\\test.csv')

# handle zip codes in a special way
df['zipcode'] = df['zipcode'].astype(str).str.zfill(5)
df.dtypes


# workign with ONLY records that have SOME office area'; don't want to conduct training on non-officearea records
df1 = df[df['officearea']!=0]
df1.shape
list(df1)


df1 = df1.fillna(0)
df1.shape               



# Specify the features of interest
features = ['block','zipcode','policeprct','healthcenterdistrict','healtharea','sanitboro','sanitdistrict']

# Extract the instances and target
X = df1[features]
y = df1.officearea


# Create a new matplotlib figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

viz = FeatureImportances(GradientBoostingClassifier(), ax=ax)
viz.fit(X, y)
viz.poof()
```

I'm getting this error from something in my dataframe.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-402-0e8d46c0d89f>", line 5, in <module>
    viz.fit(X, y)

  File "C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yellowbrick\features\importances.py", line 136, in fit
    super(FeatureImportances, self).fit(X, y, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\yellowbrick\base.py", line 311, in fit
    self.estimator.fit(X, y)

  File "C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\gradient_boosting.py", line 1395, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'], dtype=DTYPE)

  File "C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 756, in check_X_y
    estimator=estimator)

  File "C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 527, in check_array
    array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, order=order)

  File "C:\Users\Excel\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py", line 538, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '00nan'
```

I can't seem to figure out what is causing the problem, and thing downstream are failing because of this issue.  The weird thing is, when I look in the data set, there is nothing at all with '00nan'.  What is the easiest path forward here?  Thanks for the look.

Comment: Without seeing any of your code, your traceback, or your data, there is no way any of us can help you.

Comment: When you report a Python error, include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in there.

Comment: Sorry.  Just updated my original post with more info.

Comment: [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) has an argumant called `na_values`.   Try to do `df = pd.read_csv('C:\\path_here\\test.csv', na_values="00nan")`

Answer (score 0):

A combination of two things worked for me.

```
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\path_here\\test.csv', na_values='00nan')

df1 = df1.dropna(axis='columns')
```

So, the final, working, section of code looks like this.

```
# import required libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from yellowbrick.features.importances import FeatureImportances


# First, let’s load the data:
# read the data
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\path_here\\test.csv', na_values='00nan')

# handle zip codes in a special way
df['zipcode'] = df['zipcode'].astype(str).str.zfill(5)
df.dtypes


# workign with ONLY records that have SOME office area'; don't want to conduct training on non-officearea records
df1 = df[df['officearea']!=0]
df1.shape
list(df1)


# handle NANs
df1 = df1.dropna(axis='columns')
df1 = df1.fillna(0)
df1.shape               

# Specify the features of interest
features = ['block','zipcode','policeprct','healthcenterdistrict','healtharea','sanitboro','sanitdistrict']

# Extract the instances and target
X = df1[features]
y = df1.officearea


# Create a new matplotlib figure
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

viz = FeatureImportances(GradientBoostingClassifier(), ax=ax)
viz.fit(X, y)
viz.poof()
```

Thanks for pushing me in the right direction, ggrelet!!